# Repairing/salvaging fan forced heater

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, heater

I have fan forced heater (Pelonis HF-1030TB) that recently starting giving off burning smells whenever I turned on the heat. I opened it and saw that one of the contacts was burnt. Can someone please help me suggest how to repair this, and if not, what parts are worth salvaging (or how to dispose off the heater properly so that it gets recycled/reused)?

The solution I have in mind is to just replaced the burnt contact (shown in picture below). If someone can tell me what type of contact this is, that would be great. If I repair female contact on the red wire, do I also need to do the same for the male contact (looks like it is glued to the white housing). Also, how do I prevent this from happening in the future?

Please let me know if clearer pictures would help

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do a search with heater model and problems, to see if this is a common problem.  Good chance you are not the only one.  White housing looks from here might need replacing.  Burned looks where contact is attached, probably from loosed mounting.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the female spade connector on the red wire is fried. If there's enough slack in that wire, you can cut off the connector and burnt wire. Go to an appliance repair store to get a match on the old connector. You could probably find similar ones at your home store but the ratings might not be the same and you'd also want a shrink tube. These connectors are crimped on so if you don't have a crimping tool buy one or have the repair guy at the store crimp it on and shrink the tube.

Now the bad news. It looks like the problem started in the white terminal block where the rivet is attached to the male connector. This is where the arcing started and heated up the entire connection. The inside of that block is probably damaged beyond repair and would have to be replaced too. Getting parts might be a problem.

If you decide to dump the whole thing, most counties/townships have local dumping stations where you can drop off old electrical appliances for recycling.

Comment: Speedracer thanks are ok but upvotes are how we say thanks here for helpful answers, and the check mark when you accept the answer. I see this kind of damage on thermal safeties when there contacts start to fail they overhead and cause the melted wire you are seeing so be prepared to replace that device weather a safety or thermostat.

Comment: Haha I tried upvoting but I don't seem to have enough reputation for that upvote to count (at least that's what stackexchange tells me). But based on everyone's response I will try to get this device recycled or at least salvage the motor and the fan blade for another project.

Comment: @Speedracer1702 I upvoted your question because you took pictures and gave us the model number...